# Change radius of a circle

Tags: modeling

For my current model I need a series of concentric circles, and I haven't fully decided the proportions. Is there a way in which I could create them and alter their radiuses after?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in one mesh you create a set of circles of each a different radius, you can adjust the radii individually by moving your cursor over an edge/vertex of any of the circles and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>. This will select all geometry linked to the element under your mouse cursor.

Then you can change the radius of the circle by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> to  scale it, this is a freeform operation. If you want to specify the exact radius that the Circle should be then you can use an [addon described here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41199/47) called "LoopTools" (it comes with Blender, you just have to enabled it)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the radius of a cirle by scaling it 
By scaling up with factor 2, the radius will be scaled too by the factor of 2.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Another way to change the radius of a circle in Blender (see also accompanying screenshot):

1. Choose Object Mode
2. Select your circle
3. Choose Edit Mode
4. Choose Object Properties "tab"
5. Change the X and Y coordinates to the desired radius

Done!